# Subscription mail with no items "Only the top 0 posts shown"

Tags: feature-request, bug, email-notification

I once more got a subscription mail that showed no items and (correctly) said "Only the top 0 posts shown."

[image]

Please stop sending these useless mails.

Comment: Just curious after more than three months: When will this be fixed?